# Can't import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython

Tags: python, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to locally test a function i've written, but keep getting the error "cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython" which causes attempts to run the function to fail

I've made sure i'm running python 3.9 for compatibility, and the most recent version of azure functions core tools, as specified on the microsoft troubleshooting web page. Does anyone know of another work around for this?

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @howlieT

Comment: Unfortunately that was a workaround i'd tired before @Jahvani, but thank you!

Comment: Still same error you are facing? @howlieT

Comment: I am yep @Jahnavi

Comment: Have you tried all the approaches given? @howlieT

Comment: I have yes @Jahnavi

Answer (score 1):

> Can't import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython: -

According to the [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/recover-python-functions.md#troubleshoot-cannot-import-cygrpc), *"can't import name `'cygrpc'`"* error occurs when there is a mismatch in the configuration between Python interpreter and Os architecture.

*Verify the bitness of Python interpreter using below command.*

```py
py -c 'import platform; print(platform.architecture()[0])'
```

[image]

And this error might also be caused due to the Python version incompatibility with Azure functions worker as Azure functions worker accepts `Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9`only. Refer above given MS Doc for more detailed information.

*Check Python version using below command:*

`py --version`

To resolve this issue, try using [`py -m pip install grpcio`](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/) to import the package instead `grpc` package. Recently the versions of `grpc` python library got renamed as `grpcio` to avoid potential naming conflicts.

*Note*: Make sure that the `python` version is `3.7` if you are using this workaround.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Windows - I had successfully resolved the issue by changing the "defaultRuntimeVersion" to "3.11" in the file worker.config.json that could be found in the folder \Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python. This fix worked for az core tool v 4.0.5571